# fuse-box caused GET http://localhost:4444/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, typescript, p5.js

I got `GET http://localhost:4444/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` with fuse-box and P5.js. The full code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter)

The `fuse.js` looks like this:

```
const { FuseBox, WebIndexPlugin } = require("fuse-box");
const fuse = FuseBox.init({
    homeDir : "sketch",
    target : 'browser@es6',
    output : "dist/$name.js",
    sourceMaps: true,
    globals: { "p5": "p5" },
    plugins : [
        WebIndexPlugin()
    ]
})
fuse.dev(); // launch http server
fuse.bundle().instructions(" > sketch.ts +p5").hmr().watch();
fuse.run();
```

The `sketch/sketch.ts` looks like this:

```
var sketch = (p: p5) => {

    const morph = new Morph();

    p.preload = () => {

    }

    p.setup = () => {
        p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
        morph.setup(p);
    }

    p.windowResized = () => {
        p.resizeCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    }

    p.draw = () => {
        p.background(100);
        morph.draw(p);        
    }
}

var sketchP = new p5(sketch);
```

Does anyone has idea what I missed in the code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the [solution](https://github.com/mictadlo/p5-typescript-fuse-box-starter/commit/0137c2de19f601fd989ec88758196e8d32e6a423) and can be found on GitHub.